# Efficient search for series of values in an array? Ideally OpenCL usable?

Tags: c, arrays, search, opencl

I have a massive array I need to search (actually it's a massive array of smaller arrays, but for all intents and purposes, lets consider it one huge array). What I need to find is a specific series of numbers. Obviously, a simple for loop will work:

```
Pseudocode:
for(x = 0; x++) {
  if(array[x] == searchfor[location])
    location++;
  else
    location = 0;
  if(location >= strlen(searchfor))
    return FOUND_IT;
}
```

Thing is I want this to be efficient. And in a perfect world, I do NOT want to return the prepared data from an OpenCL kernel and do a simple search loop.

I'm open to non-OpenCL ideas, but something I can implement across a work group size of 64 on a target array length of 1024 would be ideal.

I'm kicking around ideas (split the target across work items, compare each item, looped, against each target, if it matches, set a flag. After all work items complete, check flags. Though as I write that, that sounds very inefficient) but I'm sure I'm missing something.

Other idea was that since the target array is uchar, to lump it together as a double, and check 8 indexes at a time. Not sure I can do that in opencl easily.

Also toying with the idea of hashing the search target with something fast, MD5 likely, then grabbing strlen(searchtarget) characters at a time, hashing it, and seeing if it matches. Not sure how much the hashing will kill my search speed though.

Oh - code is in C, so no C++ maps (something I found while googling that seems like it might help?)

Comment: what about memmem() - are you allowed gnu extensions?

Comment: Hashing is not going to help you.  It is more expensive to compute a hash of n items than it is to just perform a comparison on each one.

Comment: Multiplexing the data by treating them as having a different type produces undefined behavior in C99, which seems like a particularly bad problem in an OpenCL context, with its focus on heterogeneous hardware.  It will also require you to read data via misaligned pointers, which itself also yields undefined behavior.

Comment: Unless the data have some kind of structure that you can leverage to simplify the search, there really is no good way other than a straight-up search.  You can split up the work array into chunks and search each one in parallel, however.  Be sure to overlap the ends of the chunks so that your target doesn't evade detection by being split across two chunks.  That seems much more straightforward than splitting up the *target*, and it has the advantage that any task that locates the target can quit early.

Comment: Use memchr() to search for an location in the array equal to the first character of the search string, then compare the strings. memchr() is usually optimized depending on the compiler you're using.

Comment: Given the comments above, I just went with a straight search, each work item getting a portion of the job, each able to go over it's search 'portion' in the case that it's currently in a run of matches. Thanks for the input. I was hoping for something faster.

Comment: Note: your pseudocode is wrong. Consider the case where array is `ababc` and searchfor is `abc`

Comment: Aah I see what you're saying - the 'not match' must also be considered for the start of a new match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments above, for future searches, it seems a simple for loop scanning the range IS the most efficient way to find matches given an OpenCL implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index array[sizeof uchar]. For each uchar in the search string make array[uchar] = position in search string of first occurence of uchar. The rest of array contains -1.

```
unsigned searchindexing[sizeof char] = { (unsigned)-1};
memcpy(searchindexing + 1, searchindexing, sizeof char - 1);
for (i = 0; i < strlen(searchfor); i++)
  searchindexing[searchfor[i]] = i;
```

If you don't start at the beginning, an uchar occuring more than one time will get the wrong position entered into searchindexing.

Then you search the array by stepping strlen(searchfor) unless finding an uchar from searchfor.

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXARRAYLEN; i += strlen(searchfor))
  if ((unsigned)-1 != searchindexing[array[i]]) {
    i -= searchindexing[array[i]];
    if (!memcmp(searchfor, &array[i], strlen(searchfor)))
      return FOUND_IT;
  }
```

If most of the uchar in array isn't in searchfor, this is probably the fastest way. Note the code has not been optimized.

Example: searchfor = "banana". strlen is 6. searchindexing['a'] = 5, ['b'] = 0, ['n'] = 4 and the rest a value not between 0 to 5, like -1 or maxuint. If array[i] is something not in banana like space, i increments by 6. If array[i] now is 'a', you might be in banana and it can be any of the 3 'a's. So we assume the last 'a' and move 5 places back and do a compare with searchfor. If succes, we found it, otherwise we step 6 places forward.